# UTF encoding method for persion support in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I inserted some data in to MySQL database tables, it's actually fine inside MySQL database, but shows me the data in browser like this

> (???? ???????? ???? ???? ? ????????? ????? ? ???? ?? ???? ? ?????????
>   ?? ???? ??? ? ???? ????? ???? ?????? ??? ?????? ?? ????? ????? ???????
>   ?? ???? ??? ? ?? )

but the actual data is

> ( تولید سادگی نامفهوم از
>   صنعت چاپ و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است. چاپگرها و متون بلکه
>   روزنامه و مجله در ستون و سطرآنچنان که لازم است و برای شرایط فعلی
>   تکنولوژی )

I changed the character set to **UTF-8** and collation to utf8_general_ci, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: There are various components in your tool chain, all of them have to be configured to use the correct encoding, not only your database.

Comment: Given @arkascha's point, if you want this to be answerable, you're going to need to show your php code ([mcve])

Comment: The probable cause is failure to declare the `CHARACTER SET` for the _column_ to be utf8 (or utf8mb4).  There is no way to recover the Arabic from the question marks.